# javac -sourcepath option not working

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I am at `C:\` and from here I want to compile my `Bingo.java` source file which resides in `C:\Users\Devashish\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Bingo\src\bingo\Bingo.java`. If I understand `-sourcepath` properly, it is used to tell the java compiler where to look for `.java` source files.

I tried the following to set `-sourcepath` but none seem to work:

`C:\>javac -sourcepath C:\Users\Devashish\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Bingo\src\`
 `bingo\Bingo.java`

`C:\>javac -sourcepath C:\Users\Devashish\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Bingo\src\bingo\`   `Bingo.java`

Even these...

`C:\>javac -sourcepath C:\Users\Devashish\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Bingo\src`   `bingo\Bingo.java`

`C:\>javac -sourcepath C:\Users\Devashish\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Bingo\src\bingo`    `Bingo.java`

All above give the File not found error.

I would like to mention that compiling without `-sourcepath` from the same location works fine:

`C:\>javac C:\Users\Devashish\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Bingo\src\bingo\Bingo.java`

I believe I'm doing something very stupid here but can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-sourcepath` defines OTHER `.java` files that should be in your project. for example:

You have "C:\A.java":

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       B.hello();
    }
}
```

And C:\dir\B.java:

```
public class B {
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

In this case, when you compile and run you need sourcepath to C:\dir\B.java.

EDIT: Classpath (`-cp`) is for `.class`, Sourcepath (`-sourcepath`) is for `.java`.

Comment: I think I got it. I have another source file at `.....\src\bingo\utils\Utils.java` and which is accessed from within `Bingo.java`. This works now `javac -sourcepath C:\Users\Devashish\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Bingo\src\bingo\utils\ C:\Users\Devashish\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Bingo\src\bingo\Bingo.java`

Comment: Great! You understanded -sourcepath! PS: I think you could do -sp.

Comment: There is no variant for -sp in javac. You can use --source-path or -sourcepath.

Comment: javac -classpath and javac -sourcepath seem to work identically.